# Final Fields Semantics in Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, final, jls

This is from JLS 17.5:

> The usage model for final fields is a simple one. Set the final fields for an
>   object in that object's constructor. **Do not write a reference to the object being
>   constructed in a place where another thread can see it before the object's constructor
>   is finished.** If this is followed, then when the object is seen by another thread,
>   that thread will always see the correctly constructed version of that object's final
>   fields. It will also see versions of any object or array referenced by those final
>   fields that are at least as up-to-date as the final fields are.

The discussion in JLS 17.5 includes this sample code:

```
class FinalFieldExample {
    final int x;
    int y;
    static FinalFieldExample f;

    public FinalFieldExample() {
        x = 3;
        y = 4;
    }

    static void writer() {
        f = new FinalFieldExample();
    }

    static void reader() {
        if (f != null) {
            int i = f.x; // guaranteed to see 3
            int j = f.y; // could see 0
        }
    }
}
```

I tried reusing this code to replicate the situation above, and here is what I have:

```
public class FinalFieldThread extends Thread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadA threadA = new ThreadA();
        ThreadB threadB = new ThreadB();

        threadB.start();
        threadA.start();
        //threadB.start();

    }
}

class ThreadA extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("ThreadA");
        FinalFieldExample.writer();
    }
}

class ThreadB extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("ThreadB");
        FinalFieldExample.reader();
    }
}
```

I can test how final gets read correctly, but how can I replicate when it is not read correctly (i.e. when there is a reference to the tread before the constructor is finished?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### What you are looking for

What you are trying to test is called **Don't publish the "this" reference during construction** or **Visibility Hazard**. Read the following links in the order they are provided.

### Reading

1. [Java theory and practice: Safe construction techniques](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0618/index.html)
2. [JSR 133 (Java Memory Model) FAQ](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html)
3. [Do the ‘up to date’ guarantees for values of Java's final fields extend to indirect references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830739/do-the-up-to-date-guarantees-for-values-of-javas-final-fields-extend-to-indir)

### Sample Code

```
class FinalField
{
    final int x;
    int y;

    public FinalField()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new TestThread(this));
        t.start();

        y = 4;
        x = 3;
    }
}

class TestThread implements Runnable
{
    FinalField f;
    TestThread(FinalField f)
    {
        if(f.x != 3)
            System.out.println("value of x = " + f.x);

        this.f = f;
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        if(f.x != 3)
            System.out.println("value of x = " + f.x);
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
            new FinalField();
        }
    }
}
```

***`Output`***

```
value of x = 0
value of x = 0
value of x = 0
.
.
.
value of x = 0
value of x = 0
value of x = 0
```

### Explanation of the output

When I access the final field in the constructor of my thread then at that time the `final` field `x` was not properly initialized, and that's why we are getting `0`. ***`Whereas`*** when I access the same field in the `run()` then by that time the `final` field `x` is initialized to `3`. This is happening because of the `escaping` of the reference to the object of `FinalField`. Read the [1st](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0618/index.html) link I have shared, it is much more detailed.

Comment: Put `public FinalField() {          Thread t = new Thread(new  estThread(this));         t.start();          try {             Thread.sleep(200);        } catch (InterruptedException e) {           
        }       y = 4;        x = 3;    }` in the constructor and you get `x` to be `0` in the run method, I don't get what is the difference in your example between the final and non-final fields

Comment: That is obvious, when you said `t.start();` then you have started a new thread but when you are calling the `Thread.sleep(200);` then you are calling it on the main thread (or the thread which has created the test thread). Now when your **main** thread is waiting then in-between execution of the test thread happens (which in turn calls the `run`). Now, till this point the final field is not initialized and hence you get `x=0`, which is known as escaping of `this`.

Comment: Now what you are trying to do is to deliberately introduce a delay in the main thread and due to which the other thread could see the uninitialized **`final`** field. The question above talks about the correct usage model for final fields and that too in a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: ok, I got your point but, I still don't see any difference in the behaviour of final and non final fields, here: ` If this is followed, then when the object is seen by another thread, that thread will always see the correctly constructed version of that object's final fields. ` the JLS specifies final fields and in some way it differentiate them from non-final fields... do you get my point?

Comment: You should always initialize final fields either during declaration or in the class constructor. Now consider the case of an immutable class. If I leak the `this` while constructing the object then there will be two versions of the immutable object `1)` Properly constructed, and `2)` Improperly constructed one. This goes against the philosophy of immutable objects. Also, for a given class the final field should have a unique value for its entire life-time, which is not the case if you leak the `this`.

Comment: If final field is an object rather than primitive, then is it guaranteed that update of that final field by one thread will be seen by other thread correctly, without any additional synchronization?

Comment: @Favonius Sorry for my naive question - but why not enforce at compile time that `this` cannot be used in constructor?

Comment: @Sundeep - Check this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html