# How String class is thread safe in java?

Tags: java, string, multithreading

```
public class ThreadString extends Thread {
    String str = "ABC";

    public void run() {
        str = "abc";
    }
}
```

if threads are accessing above run method,
reference to the "ABC" now pointing to "abc" how it will works internally?

Comment: `String` is immutable. All you are doing is modifying a reference.

Comment: This class is not thread-safe.

Comment: Well, you're title asks something different, than your text. If you want to get an answer for your question in the title, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303532/immutable-objects-are-thread-safe-but-why) or [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25224033/does-immutability-guarantee-thread-safety).

Comment: @AndyTurner, If that's the complete definition of `ThreadString`, then what's not "thread-safe" about it?  "thread-safe" doesn't mean there's no thread-unsafe way to _use_ the class.  There are thread-unsafe ways to use _any_ class.  Thread-safe only means that overlapped access from multiple threads won't make any of the methods violate their API contract or put any of the class's data into a bad state.  There are no obvious invalid states for the `ThreadString` class's data, and the class's only method just performs a single, atomic operation.

Comment: The immutable class in itself is thread safe but reference of immutable class is not thread safe. You are using a String reference in your class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`String`s in Java are immutable. You aren't modifying the `String`, you're just pointing to another value. From that point of view, it's thread safe - `str` is either `"ABC"` or `"abc"`, it can't be something invalid or illegal.

Comment: `str` can be set to anything: the field is not private.