# final Fields In The Java Memory Model

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, final, java-memory-model

Could you explain how the value of f.y could be seen 0 instead of 4? 
Would that be because other thread writes updates the value to  0 from 4?
This example is taken from jls https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5

```
 class FinalFieldExample { 
        final int x;
        int y; 
        static FinalFieldExample f;

        public FinalFieldExample() {
            x = 3; 
            y = 4; 
        } 

        static void writer() {
            f = new FinalFieldExample();
        } 

        static void reader() {
            if (f != null) {
                int i = f.x;  // guaranteed to see 3  
                int j = f.y;  // could see 0
            } 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: "guaranteed to see 3" this is not true too, java does not even consider most of fields really "final", as can be changed via reflections or field can be read before initialising it in constructor.

Comment: Also you didn't describe what you are doing here, when that `reader` method will be executed?

Comment: @GotoFinal Your assertions about "not really final" are... just not correct.

Comment: @chrylis I think the main point here is that despite `x` being `final`, it can be seen with two different values from another thread: with `0` before `x = 3;` was executed, and with `3` afterwards.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak nope, this is the case for `y`, but we are not talking about reflection, it's just about safe publication and final fields.

Comment: @chrylis explain then? final field should never change value in runtime - in java it does, as it is just normal field that just needs to be initialised in constructor, but you can use that object before constructor finish and then other objects can see that value change. Also you can just change field using reflections - and java does not track this, so it also is unable to do bigger optimalizations to final fields. There was even once proposal to change this: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-compiler-dev/2015-June/018342.html

Comment: @GotoFinal To be clear, though, the "guaranteed to see 3" comment is from the JLS. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-17.html#d5e35661

Comment: @Radiodef ah, now it makes more sense about real issue. So this can be 0 from other thread due to CPU cache etc, but for final fields it is guaranteed to not be an issue.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak No, you are *guaranteed* not to see `x == 0` anywhere.

Comment: @chrylis anywhere? https://ideone.com/ieKmMz

Comment: This is already answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653739/about-reference-to-object-before-objects-constructor-is-finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could you explain how the value of `f.y` could be seen 0 instead of 4?

In Java, one of the important optimizations performed by the compiler/JVM is the reordering of instructions.  As long as it doesn't violate the language specifications, the compiler is free to reorder all instructions for efficiency reasons.  During object construction, it is possible for an object to be instantiated, the constructor to finish, and its reference published *before* all of the fields in the object have been properly initialized.

However, Java language says that if a field is marked as `final` then it must be properly initialized by the time the constructor finishes.  To quote from the section of the [Java language specs you reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5).  Emphasis is mine.

> An object is considered to be completely initialized when its constructor finishes. A thread that can only see a reference to an object after that object has been completely initialized is guaranteed to see the **correctly initialized values for that object's final fields**.

So by the time the `FinalFieldExample` is constructed and assigned to `f`, the `x` field *must* be properly initialized to 3 however the `y` field may or may not have been properly initialized.  So if thread1 makes the call to `writer()` and then thread2 makes the call to `reader()` and sees `f` as not null, `y` could be 0 (not yet initialized) or 4 (initialized).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that we have two threads started, like this:

```
new Thread(FinalFieldExample::writer).start(); // Thread #1
new Thread(FinalFieldExample::reader).start(); // Thread #2
```

We might observe our program's actual order of operations to be the following:

1. `Thread #1` writes `x = 3`.
2. `Thread #1` writes `f = ...`.
3. `Thread #2` reads `f` and finds that it is not `null`.
4. `Thread #2` reads `f.x` and sees `3`.
5. `Thread #2` reads `f.y` and sees `0`, because `y` does not appear to be written yet.
6. `Thread #1` writes `y = 4`.

In other words, `Threads #1` and `#2` are able to have their operations interleave in a way such that `Thread #2` reads `f.y` before `Thread #1` writes it.

Note also that the write to the `static` field `f` was allowed to be reordered so that it appears to happen before the write to `f.y`. This is just another consequence of the absence of any kind of synchronization. If we declared `f` as also `volatile`, this reordering would be prevented.

---

There's some talk in the comments about writing to `final` fields with reflection, which is true. This is discussed in [§17.5.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.3):

> In some cases, such as deserialization, the system will need to change the `final` fields of an object after construction. `final` fields can be changed via reflection and other implementation-dependent means.

It's therefore possible in the general case for `Thread #2` to see any value when it reads `f.x`.

There's also a more conventional way to see the default value of a `final` field, by simply leaking `this` before the assignment:

```
class Example {
    final int x;

    Example() {
        leak(this);
        x = 5;
    }

    static void leak(Example e) { System.out.println(e.x); }

    public static void main(String[] args) { new Example(); }
}
```

I think that if `FinalFieldExample`'s constructor was like this:

```
static FinalFieldExample f;

public FinalFieldExample() {
    f = this;
    x = 3; 
    y = 4; 
}
```

`Thread #2` would be able to read `f.x` as `0` as well.

This is from [§17.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5):

> An object is considered to be *completely initialized* when its constructor finishes. A thread that can only see a reference to an object **after that object has been completely initialized** is guaranteed to see the correctly initialized values for that object's `final` fields.

The more technical sections of specification for `final` contain wording like that as well.

Comment: "Thread #2 reads f.y and sees 0, because y is not yet written.": not because `y` is not yet written, but because `y` is not safely published. The initialization should already be completed when thread 2 reads a new reference of `f`. However whether it reads the up-to-date value of `y` is not guaranteed.

Comment: Reading the default value of a field can also happen without leaking the `this` reference, as long as it is not safely published (which means using volatile, final or in synchronized block etc.)

Comment: *"not because y is not yet written, but because y is not safely published"* The JLS is written in terms of ordering, i.e. in absence of synchronization we may observe the read to happen before the write.

Comment: Well, it seems like I was wrong about the order of reference assignment and the constructor. Thread 2 can see a new reference before the constructor finishes (I'm still not sure though...).  What I was trying to explain is even `y` has been set to 4 by thread 1, thread 2 is not guaranteed to see it because of local cache.